# Plotly: Sunburst plot missing sections

Tags: python, plotly, sunburst-diagram, plotly-express

When plotting data using `plotly.graph_object` sunburst some labels are missing when compared to same data plotted with `plotly.express` sunburst

Plot missing the outermost sections:

[image]

Data is still there because when expanded it the data moves from other parents to their intended place

Graph showing the motion of the data: [image]

you can see "btnCancel" moving over from "dlgMessageBox" to "frmRibbonConfigureOffsets"

Here is same data plotted with express: [image]

Code used:

```py
    # results is a pandas dataframe after some formatting and data analysis
    # extract needed data to form a list data
    p = results["Parent Name"] .to_list()
    n = results["Control Name"].to_list()
    c = results["Count"]       .to_list()
    # parents requiere "" parents with 0 val, but can't have duplicates
    pRed = results["Parent Name"].drop_duplicates().to_list()
    
    # make plot grid and set plot types acordingly
    fig = subplots.make_subplots(rows=1, cols=2, specs=[[{"type": "pie"}, {"type": "pie"}]])
    fig.add_sunburst(
        parents = ["" for _ in pRed] + p,   # parent list, parents of parents are ""
        labels  =              pRed  + n,   # data lable list
        values  = [ 0 for _ in pRed] + c,    # values, parents have 0
        row=1, col=1
    )
    # this second plot is to be replaced by a different type of plot later
    fig.add_sunburst(
        parents = ["" for _ in pRed] + p,   # parent list, parents of parents are ""
        labels  =              pRed  + n,   # data lable list
        values  = [ 0 for _ in pRed] + c,    # values, parents have 0
        row=1, col=2
    )
    # show plots
    fig.show()
    # express plot for comparasin
    expressPlot = px.sunburst(
        results,
        path=[ "Parent Name", "Control Name" ],
        values="Count"
    )
    expressPlot.show()
```

Any other formatting of the data passed to the labels/parents results in empty plots

Answer (score 0):

I managed to reproduce your issue despite the missing DataFrame in your question. The main problem is you have two children named `btnCancel`:

- One with `dlgMessageBox` parent
- One with `frmRibbonConfigureOffsets` parent

If you look closely at the plot generated by Plotly express, you have ids corresponding to your children with the following format: `parent_name/child_name`. This is a secure way to avoid issues as each ID is unique.

If you want to make subplots instead of using `plotly.express`, you need to add `ids` in your plot. Here is the full **reproducible** code below.

```py
import pandas as pd
from plotly import subplots
import plotly.express as px

# Data used in the example
results = pd.DataFrame({"Parent Name": ["dlgMessageBox"]*3 + ["frmMainForm"]*3 + ["frmRibbonConfigureOffsets"]*2,
                        "Control Name":["btnOK", 'btnCancel', 'btnYes'] + ['LeftSlidePanel', 'Something', 'Ribbon1'] 
                        + ['btnCancel', 'btnSave'],
                        "Count": [1, 1, 7, 3, 3, 1, 2, 2]})

# extract needed data to form a list data
p = results["Parent Name"] .to_list()
n = results["Control Name"].to_list()
c = results["Count"]       .to_list()
# parents requiere "" parents with 0 val, but can't have duplicates
pRed = results["Parent Name"].drop_duplicates().to_list()
    
# make plot grid and set plot types acordingly
fig = subplots.make_subplots(rows=1, cols=2, specs=[[{"type": "pie"}, {"type": "pie"}]])

fig.add_sunburst(
    parents = ["" for _ in pRed] + p,   # parent list, parents of parents are ""
    labels  =              pRed  + n,   # data lable list
    values  = [ 0 for _ in pRed] + c,    # values, parents have 0
    ids     = [a + '/' + b if a != "" else b for a, b in zip(["" for _ in pRed] + p, pRed  + n)],    # ids to avoid conflict
    row=1, col=1
)
# this second plot is to be replaced by a different type of plot later
fig.add_sunburst(
    parents = ["" for _ in pRed] + p,   # parent list, parents of parents are ""
    labels  =              pRed  + n,   # data lable list
    values  = [ 0 for _ in pRed] + c,    # values, parents have 0
    ids     = [a + '/' + b if a != "" else b for a, b in zip(["" for _ in pRed] + p, pRed  + n)],    # ids to avoid conflict
    row=1, col=2
)
# show plots
fig.show()
```